# Ethereum Wallet , Will it ever stop to sync?

Tags: ethereum

I am wondering after two days if the etherium wallet will ever stop to sync. it seems as if the number of nodes keeps increasing as well as the chain structure. I am for god sake, two days ?

And if I go had and launch the application, nothing happens when I create an account. I entered a password, and confirm it, but then nothing happens .

Comment: Please, don't ask multiple questions in a single thread. Also, this is probably off topic on Stackoverflow. You could try again at, [ethereum.stackexchange.com](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Since there are [new blocks generated every 15 seconds](https://ethstats.net/), it will *literally* never stop to sync.

You can check if your client fully updated your blockchain if you compare the block height with a block explorer like [live.ether.camp](http://live.ether.camp/).